# Copying an "x" amount of filtered rows

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Is there a way to only copy and paste an amount of loans you set to a variable on an already filtered set of data?

I have a datasheet that will get filtered for one type of loan, "ASC" in this case. After I do the autofilter there are 800 total "ASC" loans spread throughout the filtered range. The rows where "ASC" loans are located isn't continuous (they could be on rows 1, 2, 5, 9, 110, 500 etc). I know I can use below code to filter for "ASC" loans:

```
'Filter for ASC Loans
COREraw.Range("Q1").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="ASC"
```

But how can I only copy the first 100 "ASC" labeled loans from the filtered view? I'm not sure how to select the proper range since if I do the following:

```
COREraw.Range("A1:AG100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
stratSamp.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Strat_Sample").Range("A1")
```

It won't work because some of my first 100 loans of ASC could be further down the range of the entire sheet past row 100.

Is the only way to copy over a certain amount of filtered rows by going through each visibleRow and copying individually instead of copying as a group? Or would you have to do a COUNT of the visible cells and count to 100 and somehow find the row reference?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since filtering is just setting the row height to 0 for anything that doesn't match the criteria you can use that to find your place. The problem is going to be where you are coping to. Depending on the destination sometimes the hidden cells end up on the clipboard sometimes they do not. I have seen both happen. If it is to another Excel sheet you should be OK.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Visible_Only_Selection()
Dim Starting, Ending, Selection_Size, LCount As Long
Starting = ActiveCell.Row

LCount = 0
Selection_Size = InputBox("Size of sample?", "Row count")
Do Until LCount = Selection_Size
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.Height <> 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
LCount = LCount + 1
Loop
Ending = ActiveCell.Row

Range("A" & Starting & ":AG" & Ending).Copy
Sheets("Strat_Sample").Select
Range("A1").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Using this method finds the Nth visible row down from whatever starting point you setup. I named the variables out of standard so that it would be clearer on what they represent.